# In a Managed Application Azure Marketplace deployment template, if one of the resources is a VM, how can the vendor access the vm?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-marketplace

I want to create a Managed Application offering for our app. This will have the following resources:

- VMs
- extension to run a script on the vm that fetches a script from storage
- storage account
- networking

When I create with the CLI, I use ssh keys for accessing the vm

But if i'm creating a deployment template with the template customUIDefinition where the customer will fill out parameters, how do I ensure that I have access to the VM, even though the customer will deploy into the managed resource group? I can't just write the password or public key into the template?

This doesn't seem as simple as pasting the ssh public key because then there's a key to manage

My question: is there an azure service or best practice for this?

Comment: You use Azure Key Vault: Store your SSH private keys securely in Azure Key Vault. You can then grant the necessary permissions to the Managed Identity used by the deployment template to access the SSH private keys stored in Key Vault. This way, you don't have to include the SSH private keys directly in the deployment template, ensuring better security.

Comment: Thanks @VenkatV, I understood this. However, what about access on the Key Vault side? Is this something that would have to be 'managed' each time there's a sale, through whitelisting managed resource group names through whitelisting